# Delete button removes all the children , instead of just the one with the key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have researched this topic for quite some time now, yet I still cannot make the 'Remove' button in the child component (ControlledOpenSelect) only remove the item with the key it was passed - by using the callback function.

My ControlledOpenSelect (the child component):

```
const example={'skittle':10,"carrots":20,"cars":50,"potatoes":30}

export default function ControlledOpenSelect({ourObject=example,onRemove,key}) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [product,setProduct]=React.useState('None')
  const [quantity,setQuantity]=React.useState(0)
  const [price,setPrice]=React.useState('')
  const [subTotal,setSubTotal]=React.useState(0)

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setProduct(event.target.value);
    };


  const handleClose = () => {
      setOpen(false);
    };
  const handleOpen = () => {
      setOpen(true);
    };
  
  const handleQuantity=(event)=>{
    setQuantity(event.target.value)
  }

  

  //const productList=Object.keys(ourObject)

  //const correct_price=ourObject[product]

  //React.useEffect(()=>{
  //setPrice(correct_price)
  //},[correct_price])


  //React.useEffect(()=>{
  //setSubTotal(price*quantity)
  //},[quantity,product,price])




  return (
    <div>
      <Button className={classes.button} onClick={handleOpen}>
        Open the select
      </Button>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-controlled-open-select-label">Product</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
          id="demo-controlled-open-select"
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          onOpen={handleOpen}
          value={product}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          {productList.map(
            item => <MenuItem value={item}>{item}</MenuItem>
          )}
        </Select>
        <div>
        <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Quantity" variant="outlined" onChange={handleQuantity}/>
        <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Price" variant="outlined" value={price} />
        <p>{subTotal}</p>
        </div>
      </FormControl>
      <button onClick={()=>onRemove(key)}>Remove</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My parent component FullComponent:

```
const example={'skittle':10,"carrots":20,"cars":50,"potatoes":30}


const FullComponent=({ourObject=example})=>{

const [add,setAdd]=React.useState([])
// const [remove,setRemove]=React.useState([])

const id=React.useState(_uniqueId('prefix-'));

    const handleClick=(event)=>{
        setAdd([...add,
            <ControlledOpenSelect ourObject={ourObject} id={id}/>])     
    }

    const handleRemove=(id)=>{
        const newAdd=add.filter((item)=> item.id !== id)
        setAdd(newAdd)
    }

    return (
        <>
        {add.map((item)=>{
            return (
                <>
                <ControlledOpenSelect ourObject={ourObject} key={item.id}  onRemove={handleRemove} /> 
                 </>            )
        })}
        <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
        </>
    )
}


export default FullComponent
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the id to the handleRemove method . you need to pass an inline function which passes the item.id as argument

```
onRemove={() => handleRemove(item.id)}
```

Comment: But in the props of the child I'm passing key={item.id}, so in the child , shouldnt I reffer to it as onRemove={() => handleRemove(key)}? Thank you!

Comment: Nope `key` is for helping react to keep track of the items when you are rendering the items in a list . This should help - https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children . Also when you do this `handleRemove(key)` you will get error because key is not defined .

Comment: @hector In your case, what's the point of passing Key and the delete function separately as props? In your parent component: <ControlledOpenSelect ourObject = {ourObject} onRemove = {() => handleRemove (item.id)} /> (Shyam's solution) and in the child component: onClick = {onRemove}

Comment: I have changed the child's prop in the following way                 <ControlledOpenSelect ourObject={ourObject} key={item.id}  onRemove = {() => handleRemove (item.id)} /> 
and I have  changed in the child component to       <button onClick={onRemove}>Remove</button>
, yet I still have the same problem : the Delete button removes every child - instead of just the one it finds itself in...

Comment: Is the type of item.id and id you are passing to the handleRemove is same ? . I mean for example is both of them `Number` ? Also add a console.log(id) and see what gets printed when you click on the remove button .

Comment: It seems like the id is 'undefined', yet im not sure how to change it.Should I pass into the child the id props generated by the uuid? Thanks so much !

Comment: what is the shape of your `items` and also does it have id property ?

Comment: they are objects : {'skittle':10,"carrots":20,"cars":50,"potatoes":30}, I did put he id property here :const handleClick=(event)=>{
        setAdd([...add,
            <ControlledOpenSelect ourObject={ourObject} id={id}/>])     
    } and it is defined by :const id=React.useState(_uniqueId('prefix-')); (also tried without the  defining the id with loadash but also didnt work)...